# Oracle complex query with hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is my **Sample data1**

```
CP | NP |MC |DS |NNP
--- ---- --- -- ---
A  |  B |   |   |C
C  |  D | XX|YY |E
E  |  F | ZZ|11 |
```

**Expected Output1**

```
NP |MC |DS 
--- ---- --- 
 B | ZZ|11
```

Here column "CP" and "NNP" are hierarchical (i.e.)
we will start with query like below, for a particular NP and then get the corresponding MC and DS values using the below logic

```
select MC, DS from tabl1
where NP=B
```

1. first look at **value A from column CP** and then see if
   **column NNP as a corresponding value**, here it is **C value in column NNP**
2. if there is a corresponding values form column
   CP present in NNP then look at **column CP for C** value and then see
   if NNP as corresponding value here it is **E value in column NNP** (repeated these steps until we do
   not find a corresponding entry in NNP column for column CP)
3. fetch E value corresponding values for column MC and DS

Following is my **Sample data2**

```
CP | NP |MC |DS |NNP
--- ---- --- -- ---
A  |  B | 96|KK |C
C  |  D | XX|YY |E
E  |  F | ZZ|11 |
```

**Expected Output2 (if the corresponding root values are not null then we need to fetch those as well**

```
NP |MC |DS 
--- ---- --- 
 B | 96|KK
 B | ZZ|11
```

Comment: You might be interested by [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct application of hierarchical (`connect by`) query:

```
select  connect_by_root(np) as np, mc, ds
from    sample_data
where   connect_by_isleaf = 1   -- OR:  nnp is null   (IF NEEDED, SEE BELOW)
start   with cp = 'A'
connect by cp = prior nnp
;
```

In your output, in column `NP` you have the value `B`, which is the value in the "root" row (the starting row). This is where you can use `connect_by_root`. All the other values are from the leaf row ("last" row in the hierarchy). Here is where we need to use the filter `connect_by_isleaf = 1` - the value is 0 for non-leaf rows (rows that have at least one child), and 1 for leaf rows.

Note that "leaf" means no further children. This can happen either if `NNP` is `null` OR if it is not `null` but the value is not found in the `CP` column anymore. If you only want leaf rows where `NNP` is `null`, you can change the `where` clause as shown in the code above.

**EDIT** The OP requested a modification - the output should also include the **root** row, in addition to the **leaf**, but only if either the `mc` or the `ds` value (or both) is/are not `null`. This can be achieved by changing the `where` clause, which should be:

```
...
where (connect_by_isleaf = 1) 
   or (level = 1 and (mc is not null or ds is not null))
...
```

Comment: Thank you. your query works wonderful. Sadly our requirements are evolving and was wondering if there is a feasibility to fetch sample2 output as well (I have edit my post above)

Comment: @stackuser - I believe it is possible, with a small modification. But I need to understand - you are "starting with" `cp = 'A'` (or whatever other value chosen by the user, I imagine). Then you want to walk the hierarchy, and show the "leaf" row in all cases, and in addition, show just the "root" row, as long as either `mc` or `ds` (or both) is/are not NULL. Is that it? If not, please clarify.

Comment: @stackuser - OK, I show how in an EDIT added at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE. For example:

```
with
n (cp, np, mc, ds, nnp, lvl) as (
  select cp, np, mc, ds, nnp, 1 from t where cp not in (
    select nnp from t where nnp is not null
  )
 union all
  select n.cp, n.np, n.mc, n.ds, t.nnp, n.lvl + 1
  from n
  join t on t.cp = n.nnp 
),
m as (select np, max(lvl) as max_lvl from n group by np)
select m.np, n.mc, n.ds
from n
join m on m.np = n.np and m.max_lvl = n.lvl
```

I didn't test this query for syntax issues, but the strategy is correct.